# Python accuracy_check giving 0 result for flipped classification

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification

I am using `accuracy_check` from `sklearn.metrics`

My classification test data labeling is for e.g

```
[1 1 0 0 0 1 1]
```

and Kmeans gives labels as

```
[0 0 1 1 1 0 0]
```

Basically Kmeans has classified correctly but flipped the labels. `accuracy_check` is giving 0% accuracy.

My code

```
X_full, y_full = make_blobs(n_samples=nsamples,
                            centers=2,
                            n_features=no_feat,
                            random_state=ran)

X, X_test, y, y_test = train_test_split(X_full, y_full, test_size=0.2)

kmeans = KMeans(2, random_state=3)
labels = kmeans.fit(X).predict(X_test)
acc = accuracy_score(y_test, labels)
print("KMeans:", acc)
```

Any ideas on how to implement this?

Edit : Also I cannot simply flip the labels, because sometimes it does classify correctly. And in other cases I have multiple labels as well.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For measuring how well clustering retrieves classes for which you would happen to have the labels, it is wrong to use `accuracy_score` for the reasons you pointed out. Essentially, this happens because a clustering algorithm gives arbitrary labels to its clusters. Instead, in this case, you should use the adjusted rand score, which will return the same score regardless of the labels:

```
from sklearn.metrics.cluster import adjusted_rand_score

print(adjusted_rand_score([0, 0, 1, 1], [0, 0, 1, 1]))
print(adjusted_rand_score([0, 0, 1, 1], [1, 1, 0, 0]))
```

Both should return 1.0

Answer (score 1):

Could you try something besides the accuracy score?

For instance, you could try `v_measure_score` instead of `accuracy_score`.

According to [the documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.v_measure_score.html)

> This metric is independent of the absolute values of the labels: a
>   permutation of the class or cluster label values won’t change the
>   score value in any way.